# Magento get product excluding taxprices

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get excluding product price by subtracting incl price.
Please find the attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the menu path: **System -> Configurartion -> Sales -> Tax**

and check this screencast - https://goo.gl/jvccQi

Comment: Thanks,our site is incl tax
but we just want to show the excl price in magento view page

For example:
From the screenshot;
Incl price is: 245.54

But we need 223.22 which is 245.54−22.32= 223.22

Comment: Exactly, from those settings you do this

Comment: Check this printscreen - https://goo.gl/Uar4fK

Comment: helped you with my answer?